# php switch strange anomaly

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this code where $difference=0

```
switch ($difference) 
{
case 0<=$difference && $difference<300:
         return "A";
    break;
case 300<=$difference && $difference<600:
        return "B";
    break;  
}
```

I think that switch must return A but it returs B. Whats wrong ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case statement is not outputting correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961075/case-statement-is-not-outputting-correctly), and another duplicate: [My result is not following my switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8007478/367456) (closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this merely as informative.

Switches can be used with expressions, however this is tricky to do:

```
<?php
$value = 300;
$other = 1;

switch (true) {
    case $value <= 300 && $other:
        $var = 'A';
        break;

    case $value >= 300 && !$other:
        $var = 'B';
        break;

    case $value >= 300 && $other:
        $var = 'C';
        break;

    case $value > 300 && $other:
        $var = 'D';
        break;

    default:
        $var = 'FALSE';
        break;
}

echo $var;
```

The above code will display 'C' correctly. A combination of if/else statements is equivalent but I tend to find the switch more readable. Be sure to always include a default case whose value you can rely on (or maybe return from the function, throw an exception, etc).

You can also compare other variables, types, call functions (although not recommended), etc to match the value declared in the switch statement (in this case, `true` but can be an integer, string or any other base type).

Comment: switch(true) was the solution of the problem. Putting it to my code makes it work just fine

Answer (score 1):

Switches with expressions like you are using will not be evaluated as you might think.  Use an `if` statement instead:

```
if(0<=$difference && $difference<300)
{
    return "A";
}
else if(300<=$difference && $difference<600)
{
    return "B";
}
```

Comment: Switches actually can have expressions as their cases. But in this situation using them is not appropriate, you are right.

Comment: One particular pattern with case expressions is doing a `switch (true)` and having the `switch` behave like an `if` with fall-through then :)

Comment: But what can I do if I have to cmpare 20-30 options ? I thought making 1 switch is better then 30 If else statements....   Any way how to make it with switch ?

Comment: @David:  If you look at your code, you'll note that you have to keep include `$difference` in each case, which is what `switch` blocks try to help you get away from.

Answer (score 0):

In  this case what is happening is `$difference` being equal to `0` is being interpreted as `false`.  Thus you have `switch(false)`.  Each case is evaluated as a whole and there for case 2 actually returns `false` thus matching the switch statements evaluation and returning `B`.  It also has to do with loose type checking. [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)